# How to filter keys by name, then access nested object using jq

Tags: json, filter, key, jq

Novice jq user here, struggling with the following:

I have the following json and need to filter keys based on a keyword and print out the whole object (not just the key) or certain key/value pairs. Note the nested object structure of the JSON, which is intentional.

```
{
  "timers": {
    "timerWithAKeywordAPlusBlah": {
      "count": 1,
      "max": 0,
      "min": 0      
    },
    "timerWithAKeywordB": {
      "count": 2,
      "max": 0
    },
    "timerWithAKeywordAPlusBlahBlah": {
      "count": 2385,
      "max": 2,
      "min": 1         
    }
  }
}
```

Desired output:

```
"timerWithAKeywordAPlusBlah": {
  "count": 1,
  "max": 0,
  "min": 0
},
"timerWithAKeywordAPlusBlahBlah": {
  "count": 2385,
  "max": 2,
  "min": 1
}
```

*Things I tried:*

I can print out the key name, but can't figure out how to access the whole object.

```
cat timers.json| jq '.timers | keys[] | select(contains("KeywordA")) '
```

Comment: input json is invalid: you can't have repeated `timerWithAKeywordA` keys

Comment: Is .timers supposed to be an array of objects?  Do you want the output to be valid JSON?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Thanks, that was a manually constructed example and I overlooked uniqueness constraint of the key name. Updated the description to reflect that.

Comment: @peak That's an approximate structure of the json, I'm working with. `timers` is just one of the objects that contains various timer objects.

Comment: My answer has been updated accordingly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In this response, I'm going to assume that you want the output to be valid JSON.  If you want the output to be in some other form, you can simply tack on some additional filters.

Anyway, the trick is to select the objects, not the keys, like so:

```
.timers
| with_entries( select(.key|contains("KeywordA") ) )
```

With your (modified) input, this produces:

```
{
  "timerWithAKeywordAPlusBlah": {
    "count": 1,
    "max": 0,
    "min": 0
  },
  "timerWithAKeywordAPlusBlahBlah": {
    "count": 2385,
    "max": 2,
    "min": 1
  }
}
```

You can then extract whatever details are ultimately required.

Comment: thanks a lot for the detailed response. Not sure why, but the command returns all objects even if the object's key name doesn't match the search keyword. But your command led me to an article about converting json format to something that is easier to work with. So, I ended up with the following, which might be an overkill, but it does the job: `cat timers.json | jq '.timers | to_entries | map({timer: .key, count: .value.count, max: .value.max, min: .value.min}) | .[] | select(.timer | contains("KeywordA"))'`